# IsAuthenticate is false for servicestack calls but true for mvc controllers

Tags: servicestack

I've setup .Net Core so that I can successfully login and get access to an MVC API controller behind the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization `[Authorize()]` attribute and see the logged in identity.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))
                .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .Build();
            });

            services.AddControllers();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write("Auth Info: ");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine(context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "Logged In" : "Anon");

                await next();
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost
            {
                AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
            });
        }
    }
```

I then added servicestack and am able to access endpoints anonymously.

Lastly, I added the NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider to link servicestack with the .netcore identity.

```
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] { new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings) { }}));
```

- With a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization `[Authorize()]` attribute I just get an anon call.
- With a ServiceStack `[Authenticate()]` attribute I get redirected to `Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f`

I was expecting that I could use the aspnet core authentication and combine that with service stack.  Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Using ASP.NET Identity Auth in ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identity-aspnet) docs for info on using ASP.NET Identify Auth with ServiceStack.

Make sure you start with the [mvcidentity](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) project template for a starting well known configuration with Auth examples for different endpoints.

Comment: Hey mythz, I have the mvcidentity project running but wasn't able to get AzureAdB2C running with it.

I've added my netcore setup above as well.  I think part of the problem may lie with the fact that I don't specify a default scheme to the authentication.  I was doing this as that was the recommended way to get both authentication options you see there working together.

Comment: @mark I’ve no experience with AzureAd, you can try adding a [callback on PopulateSessionFilter](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity/blob/master/MyApp/Startup.cs#L264) to further populate the ServiceStack Session to see if it gets called, otherwise it’s not considered an Authenticated Request.